# Calculating the Jacobian for sampled data

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

I am reading about the Jacobian matrix which I interpret as a generalized gradient.

I would like to take my investigations a bit further, so I have constructed some sample data which I would like to calculate the Jacobian of. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: This is more a numerical question as to "how to approximate the Jacobian of sample data".

Comment: Are u interested to have some samples in Calculus or in differential geometry?

Comment: I am not interested in samples, I am interested in calculating the jacobian of a given list of numbers.